# history/log of command-lines executed to launch processes(pid)

Tags: process, logs

Given a certain PID, is it possible to discover what command-line executed this process?

`top`, `atop`, `ps` provide real time informations, I'm looking for something whereby I can look the past, because I've seen a process taking many resources of the machine, I've killed it, but now I want to know more about it

Comment: On systems with `/proc` the "directory" for the PID usually has a `cmdline` or such "file" inside

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the general classic sense, no, it's not possible to discover that information by `PID`.  For one thing, `PID`s wrap at 64k. There may be other security packages or loggers that would retain this information.